# google sheet onKeyUp event trigger

Tags: google-sheets

it is posible to trigger app script when typing in cell? Or maybe any other solution. I'm trying to sort cities thats starts with letters that im typing in dropdown when typing inside cell...
[image]

[image]

At this moment its sort if city including letters, but i need that city starts with letters

Comment: This is unusual since Validation options are displayed in the same order as they appear in the range/list AND as soon as one letter is entered, only the options beginning with that letter are displayed OR, if there are no options beginning with that letter, then no options are displayed. So, would you please confirm: regarding the cell shown in the image displaying the letter "K"... does this contain Data validation AND have dropdown options (shown below) **not** changed to show _only_ the cities beginning with _K_ OR no options (if there are no cities beginning with the letter K)?

Comment: Would you please advise: 1) are you using a `list` or `range` for the criteria? 2) is the list/range already sorted? 3) regarding your image, do you have any cities beginning with the letter "K"?

Comment: @Tedinoz 1. range (from another colummn); 2. yes by alphabet; 3. yes

Comment: @Tedinoz At this moment its sort if city including letters, but i need that city starts with letters (first screen)

Comment: @Tedinoz I was add another screen with settings

Comment: `At this moment its sort if city including letters, but i need that city starts with letters` I'm sorry but I don't understand what this means. I can't reproduce your results: [dropdown-before](https://imgur.com/a/0cGf1ZZ) and [dropdown-after](https://imgur.com/a/Lzax3xf). As you can see, in the "after" screenshot, the options are limited to those containing "K". Also, in your 2nd screenshot, I don't understand why the list of options doesn't appear below the Criteria range. Would your please share your spreadsheet.

Comment: @Tedinoz in ur "dropdown-after" when you type ```K``` letter the first item (in dropdown) is ```Боково``` and its not start with ```K``` letter. How to sort dropdown items that starts with letter ```K``` or any letter that im typing?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it isn't possible to configure "granularity" settings for data validation.